# Teradata to Oracle migration Primary Keys and Indexes

Tags: database, oracle, teradata, exadata

I am moving from Teradata to Oracle and I have a question regarding Primary Keys and Indexes in the DDLs.

Here are several scenarios and what I am doing:

1) In Teradata there is:

```
Primary Key("X","Y")
```

then in Exadata I use:

```
constraint "PK" PRIMARY KEY ("X","Y")
USING INDEX TABLESPACE DB_NAME" ENABLE;
```

2) In Teradata there is no primary key but there is:

```
PRIMARY INDEX ("X")
```

then in Exadata I use:

```
CREATE INDEX "DB_NAME"."INDEX_NAME" ON "DB_NAME"."TABLE_NAME" ("X")
```

3) In Teradata there is no primary key but there is:

```
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ("X")
```

then in Exadata I use

```
constraint "PK" PRIMARY KEY ("X","Y")
USING INDEX TABLESPACE DB_NAME" ENABLE;
```

4) In Teradata there is no primary key but there is:

```
INDEX ("X")
```

then in Exadata I use Create Index

**As you can see, It's not entirely clear when I need to use just the Constraint Primary Key and when I need to use create index. Any help would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a primary key and an index?

Comment: You should follow Exadata's rules for creating partitioning & indexes and not simply try to copy them as-is. Physical implementation is always quite DBMS dependent. Doing it wrong might result in bad performance.

Comment: @dnoeth Can you recommend any resources for me to read so that I can learn what the best practices are?

Comment: You can use our tools to migrate your Teradata to Oracle (Exadata). SQL Developer's Migration Project will capture your Teradata objects and map them to new ones in Oracle. It can also move the data over. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/teradata-089107.html

Comment: @thatJeffSMith Thanks Jeff. We're basically there, except for a few  updates to make to some of the tables.

Comment: @Simon Harper: Sorry, but I only know the other way around, Oracle to Teradata, which is more common :-)

Comment: @thatJeffSMith Hello Jeff, how successful is the Teradata to Oracle migration tool? I'm using Teradata 14.10.01.07 and moving to Oracle 11g 11.2.0.4.0.

Is there anything that I need to know before attempting it? How correct will the translated DDLs be?

Comment: it's VERY successful @simon-harper. The translated DDL should be very close to 100% correct, but you'll have to make some decisions on how you want to translate column data types. Something to know before attempting - do the offline data migration unless you have a very small amount of data to migrate. For questions, feel free to post to our OTN Forums for SQL Developer or Migrations.

Comment: @thatJeffSMith Thanks Jeff. I've been trying out the Scratch Editor Teradata to Exadata and I think it struggles with a lot of the tables and views.

Comment: @simon-harper the scratch editor is for 'scratch' work. Build a real migration project. That way when table and column names change, the propagate down to the views and stored procs, etc. The scratch editor has no knowledge of the data model.